# Alchemy sentiments text API json parse error

Tags: json, parse-error, alchemyapi

Hi I am making the call for alchemy sentiments API as given below:

```
function getAnalysis(sentence)
{
        $.ajax({
          url:alchemy.baseUrl,//http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/text/TextGetTextSentiment`enter code here`
          type: 'POST',
          dataType:'jsonp',
          contentType:'json',
          data:{
              apikey:alchemy.acessKey,
              text:sentence,
              showSourceText:1,
              outputMode:'json'
              //outputMode:'xml'
          },
          context: this
          }).done(function(data){
              console.log('Sentiments Analysis sucessfull..');
              console.log(data);
          })
          .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

              console.log('Sentiments Analysis error:', textStatus, errorThrown);
          });
```

I am getting status 200 OK. But error in parsing : is returned from ajax call.  I have validated JSON it is correct.The json is below:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "usage": "By accessing AlchemyAPI or using information generated by AlchemyAPI, you are agreeing to be bound by the AlchemyAPI Terms of Use: http://www.alchemyapi.com/company/terms.html",
    "url": "",
    "language": "english",
    "text": "sachin is a good batsman.",
    "docSentiment": {
        "type": "positive",
        "score": "0.50098"
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the question just by modifying the ajax request and adding the callback as given below:

```
function getAnalysis(sentence)
{
        $.ajax({
          url: alchemy.baseUrl,
          type: 'POST',
          dataType:'jsonp',
          contentType:'json',
          jsonpCallback:'callback',
          data:{
              apikey:alchemy.acessKey,
              text:sentence,
              showSourceText:1,
              jsonp:'callback',
              outputMode:'json'

             },
          context: this
          }).done(function(data){
              console.log('Sentiments Analysis sucessfull..');
              console.log(data);
              var text=data.text;
              if(data.docSentiment.type==="negative")
              {
                  displayNegetiveAnalysis(text);
              }
              else if(data.docSentiment.type==="positive"){
                  displayPositiveAnalysis(text);
              }
           })
          .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

              console.log('Sentiments Analysis error:', textStatus, errorThrown);
          });
}
/*
 * Function:Callback
 * Description:passing callback to URL Call
 * 
 */
function callback(json){
    console.log(json);
}
```